# create-react-app --typescript: Cannot compile namespaces when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I generated a project with `npx create-react-app my-app-ts --typescript`,
then I created two files, `sw-build.js` and `sw.js` under `src/`,

the code of `sw-build.js` and `sw.js` is from ([Guidlines for Using Workbox](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5673#issuecomment-438654051)).

There is an error:

```
Cannot compile namespaces when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.
```

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 12):

Just for others that may end up here, a potential answer was posted on the github issue listed above: [Guidlines for Using Workbox](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5673#issuecomment-447651528).

> **karannagupta commented**
>
> I've excluded the SW files in `tsconfig.json` like this:
>
> ```
> {
>  "compilerOptions": {
>   ...
>   },
>   "include": [
>     "src/*"
>   ],
>   "exclude": [
>     "node_modules",
>     "**/*.spec.ts",
>     "src/sw-*.js",
>     "src/idb.js"
>   ]
> }
> ```

**Edit:**
Other options:

- add `// @ts-ignore` to the line above the one with the error
- add a nothing export (eg. `export const _ = '';`) so that the file is a module ([from this ts issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15230#issuecomment-449398038))

A little hacky, but might be all someone needs...

Comment: `// @ts-ignore` works as a charm. Thanks.